pycharm will not read file
import pandas as pd
dss=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\mdhea\Desktop\coursera\Data science salaries project')
print(dss.head (10))

C:\Users\mdhea\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\mdhea\PycharmProjects\data salaries\main.py" 
  File "C:\Users\mdhea\PycharmProjects\data salaries\main.py", line 2
    dss=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\mdhea\Desktop\coursera\Data science salaries project')
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Process finished with exit code 1

any help with why this wont work
import pandas as pd
dss=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\mdhea\Desktop\coursera\Data science salaries project')
print(dss.head (10))

first 10 lines in the excel csv file

Try calling read_csv with encoding='latin1', encoding='iso-8859-1' or encoding='cp1252'  or encoding='uft-8' (these are some of the various encodings found on Windows).

import pandas as pd
dss=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\mdhea\Desktop\coursera\Data science salaries project')
print(dss.head (10))

On line number 2 dss=pd.read_csv('C:\Users\mdhea\Desktop\coursera\Data science salaries project'), I think the way you put the string is wrong. You can try putting r(raw string) at the front of the string and add what type is the file at the end of the string like this:
dss=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\mdhea\Desktop\coursera\Data science salaries project.csv')
The backslashes() are used for escape sequences like \n for newline and you can put double/single quotes after a backslash inside a string surrounded by the same quotes etc..(you can search that up). Python might misinterpret it as an escape sequence.
(I'm not 100% sure if this works though... try it out)
Also, at line 3(print(dss.head (10))), you should remove the space between 'head' and '(10)".

try adding r in front of your path
import pandas as pd
dss=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\mdhea\Desktop\coursera\Data science salaries project')
print(dss.head (10))

